# IE11 enable caching in localhost

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-11

I have an IE11 related caching problem that does not occur in localhost, as for some reason, the IE11 does not use cache at all in localhost. I guess it figures it is coming from localhost so it retrieves it anyway.

**Is there a way to enable caching in localhost in IE11?** Otherwise I always need to test online, which is cumbersome. I tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, but no help

Comment: The webserver is responsible for cache control.

Comment: I know. I'm testing how well the browser (IE) works with defined cache control. For that reasons I need to be able to enable caching in localhost. As it behaves differently on server than in localhost, even the headers are the same.

Comment: You may work around this by setting up local DNS in `/etc/hosts` for windows [see here](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/10c/Local-DNS-modifications-on-Windows-etchosts-equi.html)